# Ubuntu on Google(Android) TV box for XBMC

Tags: xbmc, arm

it is possible to install ubuntu on a (android) google tv box like [this](http://www.ebay.nl/itm/Full-HD-1080P-HDMI-Google-Android-2-2-Media-Player-TV-Box-HDTV-NEW-/270879123625?pt=LH_DefaultDomain_0&hash=item3f11a768a9#ht_1724wt_1392)?

I want to make a cheap XBMC box. I have seen success on a ARM processor beagleboard. Google tv boxes dus also run an arm. 
It needs to run opengl is this possible? 
If it is possible it can give a boost for ubuntu (tv) and XBMC, a PC for 55 euro's

Update: It has a SV8860 processor, so opengl does not work. so I found a other a AMLOGIC8726 processor

Comment: this is exactly what im looking for as well. the best idea I came accross so far is appleTV. The only draw back is no usb port. because ubuntu can boot on apple/intel devices this would work but no usb port kills it for me cause I want to attach keyboard and external hd

Comment: This question appears to be abandoned and unanswered, could you perhaps add more detail to your question? If this question no longer applies then you can either delete it or answer it yourself if you've solved the problem. Thanks!

Comment: Well here in china there's a trend of flashing TV boxes due to its cheap price. I am currently working on a CM311-1a. It's a pretty modern model, with 2G RAM and 16G eMMC. The limitation is the 100 Mbps Etheret port. To flash the box, you have to get rid of the shell and connect 2 points. A bit hard work though,